# Using DBSCAN to find each cluster center, radius in Python?

Tags: python, dbscan

I want to find each cluster's center and radius. What can I do? Please help me. Here is my code it contain dbscan and meanshifts two result. The points is random and now i want to find each cluster's center and radius.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import cluster


def cluster_plots(set, colours1='gray', colours2='gray',
                  title1='Plot 1', title2='Plot 2'):
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    fig.set_size_inches(6, 3)
    ax1.set_title(title1, fontsize=14)
    ax1.set_xlim(min(set[:, 0]), max(set[:, 0]))
    ax1.set_ylim(min(set[:, 1]), max(set[:, 1]))
    ax1.scatter(set[:, 0], set[:, 1], s=8, lw=0, c=colours1)

    ax2.set_title(title2, fontsize=14)
    ax2.set_xlim(min(set[:, 0]), max(set[:, 0]))
    ax2.set_ylim(min(set[:, 1]), max(set[:, 1]))
    ax2.scatter(set[:, 0], set[:, 1], s=8, lw=0, c=colours2)
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

def data_generator():
    clust1 = np.random.normal(5, 2, (1000, 2))
    clust2 = np.random.normal(15, 3, (1000, 2))
    clust3 = np.random.multivariate_normal([17, 3], [[1, 0], [0, 1]], 1000)
    clust4 = np.random.multivariate_normal([2, 16], [[1, 0], [0, 1]], 1000)
    return np.concatenate((clust1, clust2, clust3, clust4))

datapoints  = data_generator()
bandwidths  = [cluster.estimate_bandwidth(dataset, quantile=0.1) for dataset in [datapoints]]
meanshifts  = [cluster.MeanShift(bandwidth=band, bin_seeding=True).fit(dataset) for dataset, band in zip([datapoints], bandwidths)]
dbscan      = cluster.DBSCAN(eps=1, min_samples=10, metric='euclidean').fit_predict(datapoints)

cluster_plots(datapoints, dbscan,meanshifts[0].predict(datapoints),title1='DBScan', title2='Meanshifts')
```

I don't know what should I add can get what i want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cluster center mean of DBSCAN in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039636/cluster-center-mean-of-dbscan-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN clusters do not use the concept of a center or a radius.

Clusters can be any shape, and if you consider the examples in the Wikipedia article, **the cluster"center" could be paid off the cluster** if you have such banana shaped clusters.

Either way, there is no API to get a "center". Whatever you use, you'll Haversine to find it yourself. Instead of the arithmetic mean, consider something graph based, like graph centrality.